# Icon transparency issue

Tags: c#, icons, transparency

I have created an icon with a transparent background.  When I set the icon in my main app, build the project, create a shortcut to my .exe the icon now has a white background instead of transparent.

I started a brand new test project... do the exact same thing and the icon keeps its transparency.  So now i know there is nothing wrong with my icon but for the life of me can't figure out where the white background is coming from in my main app.

The only thing in my main app that deals with transparency is the splash screen. But I'm not seeing how these would be connected in any way... I'm out of ideas on what could be causing this. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Is this for the form back ground or for your exe created and installed on the PC

Comment: This is the icon of the .exe.  VS2010 Project > Project Properties > application > icon and manifest

Answer (score 3):

Many icon files contain multiple icon sizes. Are you sure that in both test cases you are using the same icon (size) and that all icons versions are transparent?

Comment: I copied the icon out of my main project into my test app and it works fine in my test app.  I know the icon file is not the issue

Comment: Could you provide a download of the icon? The icon on the desktop is completely independent of the application. The desktop simply uses the resource from within the exe and does not start the exe.

Comment: sure, http://www.zumodrive.com/share/bx78YmQ5Mz, weird thing is my friend can create a project and get it to work find.  I for some reason can not, unless i change my icons from medium to small on the desktop

Comment: You mean to say that the Icon is transparent unless the executable is name E.exe? A little googling notified me that e.exe is a common name for a virus. Could it be that your virus scanner is interfering?

Comment: I'm not running a virus scanner on my machine.  I'm not sure i quite follow why a virus scanner would effect transparency either.  I really don't get this one... starting to wonder if my pc is using another build of my app for icon for some odd reason.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in Visual C# 2010 Express. Since this version doesn't have a "clean build" command, to fix I exited studio, then did a thorough clean: deleted contents of all debug, release and obj dirs, plus deleted the .suo file. Reloaded via the open command. Icon now had transparent background. Seems like studio is caching the icon file in one of those places. See below on clearing IconCache.db.

Comment: Actually, it *does* have a "Clean Solution" command. In the Build menu.

Comment: Hi, you're probably thinking of the Pro & Std versions, MS Visual c# 2010 Express, only has build and rebuild commands, which is not the same as a clean build. Even so, those versions probably don't flush the suo file - if that is where it is caching - unlikely though.

Comment: Update: second time around, cleaning didn't help. Turned out that the c:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\IconCache.db needs to be rebuilt. Google for instructions on how to do that. Basically, open a cmd prompt and cd to the local dir. Kill explorer. Del the db file (explorer dumps cache on exit so need to del after killing explorer). Restart explorer.

Comment: Huh, strange. VB.NET 2010 Express has it, though. I would have thought they were equivalent.

Comment: One would think so :) C# Express doesn't have an Icon Image editor either - so had to do that in VS2008 - I rolled back from using VS2010 Pro because of some IDE problems - waiting for SVP fix.  Coincidentally, I was reading Stephen Lavavej's blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) on upcoming features for C++11, which reveals how convoluted the feature release process is - to the extent that some features like the Icon editor were excluded!